# Changing text in current visual selection in Vim

Tags: vim, text-editing

I have some part of a line visually selected. I would like to remove all non-word characters in the selection and replace all whitespace characters with underscores.

How would I go on about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following assumes a basic familiarity with the Vim `:substitute` command. First replace the whitespace characters with underscores.

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\s\%V/_/g
```

Typing `:` while text is visually selected will automatically fill in

```
:'<,'>
```

The `\%V` before and after the space cause the enclosed pattern (the space) to match only within a visually-selected region. Next remove the non-word characters. Type `gv` to re-select the region. Then type

```
:'<,'>s/\%V\W\%V//g
```

where `\W` is a Vim regex atom meaning "non-word character." See

```
:help /\%V
:help /\s
:help /\W
:help gv
```

Typing the `\%V` can be awkward. The [vis.vim](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) plugin simplifies this by allowing one to execute any ex command on a visually-selected region by typing `:` then `B` then the ex command, simplifying the above to

```
:'<,'>B s/\s/_/g
gv
:'<,'>B s/\W//g
```

where again, Vim fills in the `'<,'>` part for you.

**Edit**
I replaced "space" with "whitespace characters" above after re-reading the question.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about `\%V`.